# Ajax synchronous call is not working in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

Here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: contextpath+'/servlet/AjaxManager?',
  data: 'mode='+mode+'&phone='+phoneNo,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'xml',
  async: false,
  success:function(xmlDoc) {
    var message = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("message");
    message = message[0].firstChild.data;

    if(message == 'invalid') {
      alert('invalid code entered');
    } else if(message == 'valid') {
      // security code is valid
      var con = confirm('Are you sure to Proceed ?');

      if(con==true) {   
        var conUsername=$("#country").val().concat($("#phone").val());
        $("#frmRegistration").submit();
      }
    }
  }, error:function(xmlDoc) {
    alert('Error while checking security code validity');
  }
});
```

Whenever call is made, control directly moves to error function and error alert is displayed. Same code works in other browser and in android too.

If I change:

`async : true`

then it works.

Why is it so with ipad that ajax synchronous call does not work?

Comment: Possibly related: [Synchronous AJAX call fails on iPad, but not other platforms and browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6699155)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Safari mobile simply didn't allow synchronous requests because they have the potential to lock the brower. That's just speculation on my part, though.

Comment: yes..there are many related question but no solution and if there is any solution then it is for asp.net :(

Comment: What exactly is the error message? You can get more detailed info from the error callback

Comment: no error message but it moves to error:function(xmlDoc) block and display alert their.....

Comment: The `error` callback is giving you details: `error( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown)` You just need to catch and output them. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: For identifying the type of error you getting, alert 'xmlDoc.statusText'

Comment: @Pekka웃 : I tried with error( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown) and get this error "Error : NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"